# Can you launch non-mixable audio while in background and use the remote control center?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudiosession, mpremotecommandcenter

I am initiating some background music from a local notification. I am getting the following error code: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560557684 "(null)", which is

> AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotInterruptOthers An attempt was made to
>   make a nonmixable audio session active while the app was in the
>   background. **This is allowed only when the app is the NowPlaying app.**

I cannot find a lot of documentation about what it means to become the NowPlaying App.  Currently I am calling both

```
 UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

and the NowPlayingInfo function first.

```
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: currentPodName + " - " + currentEpName,
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: currentAuthor,
        MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem!.duration),
        MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime()),
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
              return image
             })
    ]
```

before setting the AV Session

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("Playback OK")
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("Session is Active")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

I do this from

```
func userNotificationCenter(_: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

so it is called each time the local notification is received.  I continue to get the error.  Is there anything else I can do to allow my app to launch a non-mixable audio session from the background?

If I cannot launch a non-mixable audio session from the background, I can make the audio mixable, but I lose access to the MPRemoteCommandCenter, which cannot integrate with mixable music.  Is there a way to launch from the background and keep the MPRemoteCommandCenter?

Comment: You don't say where that error is coming from - is it from `setActive()`?

Comment: Yes, it's from     SetActive()

Comment: Is this from a cold start or is your app already running?

Comment: The app is running in the background.  It’s not terminated.

Comment: In that case you can have a mixable category while you're in the background, and when you get your notification, change it to non-mixable, _without_ calling `setActive()`. That should work if no other non-mixable apps are active.

Comment: I will try this and report back.

Comment: Hm, this did not work for me, but I may have been misunderstanding your suggestions. By staring with .mixWithOthers I do get the audio to play.  But I do not get the Remote Control Center. //1 //.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
//2// player.play()
//3// try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
//4// AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
//5// UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
//6// configureCommands() [locally defined function]
//7// updateNowPlayingInfo() [locally defined function]

Comment: Actually, realized I was doing step 4 wrong.  Changed it to:  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0)) and I think it is working!

Comment: strange, those step 4s should be exactly the same. Anyway, good news

Comment: That is really weird - they really should be the indistinguishable, along with Bluetooth devices with remote control buttons, CarPlay etc. I don’t suppose you have a small sample that reproduces this?